# How would I go about creating the summation formula

Tags: summation

> Consider the following program segment, where i, j , k, n, and counter are integer variables and the value of n (a positive integer) is set prior to this segment.

```
counter := 0 
for i := 1 to n do 
for j := 1 to i do 
for k : = 1 to j do 
counter := counter + 1
```

> We shall determine, in two different ways, the number of times the statement

```
counter := counter + 1
```

> is executed. (This is also the value of counter after execution of the program segment.) From the result in Example 1.39, we know that the statement is executed $$\binom{n+3-1}{3}=\binom{n+2}{3}$$ times. For a fixed value of i, the for loops involving j and k result in $$\binom{i+1}{2}$$ executions of the counter increment statement. Consequently, $$\binom{n+2}{3}= \sum_{i=1}^n \binom{i+1}{2}$$ Use this result to obtain a summation formula for
>
> $$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + .. + n^2 =  \sum_{i=1}^n i^2$$

I'm trying to figure it out, but I just don't know how to get to the answer.

Comment: I dont understood absolutely nothing... Maybe this is not a mathematical question, morelike a programming one.

Comment: See also [Faulhaber/Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clearly
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i\sum_{k=1}^j 1=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i j=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i(i+1)}{2}\\=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 +\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} +\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There is only one step that I don't get. How did you do this step:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{i+1}{2} = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i(i+1)}{2}\\$$

Comment: I'm not sure about your notation $\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{i+1}{2}$, but I got $\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$ from $\sum_{j=1}^i j$. This is essentially $1+2+\cdots i$.

Comment: @user35774 note that the binomial coefficient $\binom{i+1}{2}$ equals $\frac{(i+1)!}{(i + 1 - 2)!2!} = \frac{(i-1)!\cdot i \cdot (i+1)}{(i -1)!2!} = \frac{i(i+1)}{2}$.